# When calling a static method of class A from class B, does the main method of class A run?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I have a class Dictionary. It just reads a text file (from the main method) containing some words and stores them in a hash set. The class also has a method "contains"(static) that checks if the Hashset contains a given word or not and returns a boolean. Hashset variable is defined as static as well.

Now, if I have another program and I call the static method "contains", does the "main" method of Dictionary class run? In my program it does not seems to run as the Dictionary is empty (all calls to contains method return false). How do I make sure to run the main method and fill the dictionary?

Of course I could make the method non static and create a dictionary object OR create dictionary as an inner class in my calling program. But just want to know if there is a better way of doing this.

I will share the code if needed.

PS: Dictionary class runs fine when run independently and calls to the "contains" method work fine as well.

```
private static Set<String> dictionary = new HashSet<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        System.out.println("Reading dictionary....");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("dictionary.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s;
        while((s = br.readLine()) != null){
            dictionary.add(s);
        }
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Dictionary contains the following words");
    for(String s : dictionary){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
public static boolean contains(String inpword){
    //String[] args = new String[0];
    //main(args);
    if(dictionary.contains(inpword))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You need to specify what language you are programming in.

Comment: Are you using java or C#?

Comment: A short code sample would be good. About 10 or 20 lines should be more than enough.

Comment: I am using Java. Just added my Dictionary class. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Is there some good reason why you couldn't just test it for yourself? -1

Comment: I have tested it and it is not working. Just trying to learn alternatives in such scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Stephen below has answered my question and that is what I was expecting. Do not understand why this is flagged as off-topic when someone has already answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have another program and I call the static method "contains", does the "main" method of Dictionary class run?

No.  It does not.

> In my program it does not seems to run as the Dictionary is empty (all calls to contains method return false). How do I make sure to run the main method and fill the dictionary?

You could call the Dictionary classes `main` method explicitly.  For example:

```
    public class OtherClass {
        ....
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ...
            Dictionary.main(args);  // ... or provide a different argument list
            ...
        }
    }
```

But that's a bad idea, because `Dictionary.main` (as currently written) does more besides initializing the dictionary.  You most likely doing want the dictionary written to standard output ...

It would be a much better idea to make `Dictionary` more object-oriented:

- Make the `dictionary` variable non-static
- Make the `contains` method non-static
- Move the initialization code into a constructor
- Make the `Dictionary.main` method create a `Dictionary` instance ...

Then you can write `OtherMethod` class so that it creates and uses a `Dictionary` instance.

---

As a general rule, a class does not need a "main" method.  You should only provide one for a class that is a genuine entry point for the application.

Including a "main" for testing is old fashioned.  It is a better idea to implement the test code and harness separately; e.g. using a testing framework like JUnit or TestNG.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen. That clears all the questions I had.

Answer (score 2):

No: Calling a static method of a class does not run its `main()` method.

Answer (score 2):

The main method isn't always necessary. May I suggest you use arrays to create a mini database for the dictionary. Put items in it then call them. It's easier that way.

Also, non-static void methods don't work with static methods.